# Intellij: parameter names not resolved in code auto-completion

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, code-completion

latest Intellij IDE version 2019.1:

Attaching javadoc to external dependent jars does not resolve method parameter names. For example,

For example, an external jar has class Calculator

```
public class Calculator {
      public int add(int orginalValue, int valueToAdd) {
            return originalValue + valueToAdd;
      }
}
```

Attach its Javadoc to the external jar. Inside java editor, Javadoc for the method can be displayed with parameter names. But java editor code auto-complete (or assistant) does not show parameter names. Instead it show "i" for integer, "s" for string type, etc.  Source code for the external jars(commercial license) is not available to public.

Found a bug report
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-20473

that was reported 11 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA gets parameter names from sources and when they are absent it generates names by types. Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125988